# Calculate time difference between two hh:mm variables over the span of a day

Tags: r, time, chron

I have an issue calculating the time difference between two variables. To be exactly the time between falling asleep and waking up. I thought about using chron for doing so and this is my example.

```
DF <- data.frame(time_start = c("20:00", "21:30", "22:00", "23:00", "00:30", "02:00", "04:00"),
                 time_end = c("03:00", "06:30", "07:00", "09:00", "5:30", "09:00", "10:00"))

library(chron)
DF$time_start <- paste0(DF$time_start, ":00")
DF$time_start <- chron(times. =DF$time_start)
DF$time_end <- paste0(DF$time_end, ":00")
DF$time_end <- chron(times. =DF$time_end)
DF$time_duration <- times(DF$time_end - DF$time_start)
```

Formatting the variables with chron works partially as intended. The summary for time_end looks good. time_start on the other hand is rather messy. And time_duration is decimal.

```
> summary(DF$time_start)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
00:30:00 03:00:00 20:00:00 13:17:09 21:45:00 23:00:00 
> summary(DF$time_end)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
03:00:00 06:00:00 07:00:00 07:08:34 09:00:00 10:00:00 
> summary(DF$time_duration)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.7083333 -0.6250000 -0.5833333 -0.2559524  0.2291667  0.2916667
```

My questions:

How can I get plausible summary results for time_start and

how can I get the difference between time_start and time_end in a more readable way like hours? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the tidyverse package lubridate, and its cheat sheet.

Comment: Okay, I can shorten all the previous code by "library(lubridate)
DF$time_duration <- hm(DF$time_end) - hm(DF$time_start)" and get a readable time. But the duration is still negative, example 20:00 - 03:00 = -17h instead of 7h. How to tackle that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the right durations in case that the `end_time` is the same or the next day as `start_time`:

```
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data.frame(time_start = c("20:00", "21:30", "22:00", "23:00", "00:30", "02:00", "04:00"),
                 time_end = c("03:00", "06:30", "07:00", "09:00", "5:30", "09:00", "10:00")) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("time")), hm) %>% 
  mutate(time_duration = if_else(
    time_end > time_start,
    time_end - time_start,
    hm("24:00") - time_start + time_end)
  )

DF
  time_start  time_end time_duration
1  20H 0M 0S  3H 0M 0S      7H 0M 0S
2 21H 30M 0S 6H 30M 0S      9H 0M 0S
3  22H 0M 0S  7H 0M 0S      9H 0M 0S
4  23H 0M 0S  9H 0M 0S     10H 0M 0S
5     30M 0S 5H 30M 0S      5H 0M 0S
6   2H 0M 0S  9H 0M 0S      7H 0M 0S
7   4H 0M 0S 10H 0M 0S      6H 0M 0S
```